# Exploring an HTML table with DOM table elements versus getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, dom

All,

I need to scrape an HTML table into a JS array.  Is there a difference between exploring the table using the DOM table elements (e.g., `table.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells[0]`) and looping through the cells using their IDs (e.g., `document.getElementById('cell_i')`)?

Comment: Not really - you still end up with the DOM node at the end of it. Just use whichever method you prefer. I'm not sure what the problem is here

Comment: For example, I was wondering if when using simply the id the browser wouldn't have to scrape the entire page versus only the table in the first method.

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth. Personally, I'd use the `table.tBodies...` method first, then look for alternatives if it became a bottleneck

Comment: I expect all browsers create an index of all elements with a name or ID anyway, so lookups are very fast. But performance should not be an issue either way. Note that *bodies*, *rows*, *cells* are live collections so if performance is an issue later, consider converting to arrays before dealing with them as browsers **might** check if they've been modified on each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the table member collections provides short, clear and idiomatic code, and there are no browser compatibility issues to my knowledge.

Certainly, `getElementById()` would work, but you'd need to identify every member, or at least every cell, and that would seem cumbersome. Plus then you'd need some logic to ensure you're using the correct ID.

Both the collection lookups and the `getElementById()` will be very fast. I doubt you'll find any compelling gain either way.